# Representing a hexagon as an intersection of 6 halfplanes

Tags: geometry

how can I represent a hexagon (6-gon) as an intersection of 6 half planes?

Comment: The half planes are bounded by the sides of the hexagon.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but how can I represent it in an equation? @saulspatz

Comment: I don't understand what kind of equation you are looking for.  You should add some more details to your question.  Don't make a comment, edit the question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the type of answer you require?

$$y\le\sqrt3$$
$$y\ge-\sqrt3$$
$$y\ge \sqrt3(x-2)$$
$$y\le -\sqrt3(x-2)$$
$$y\le \sqrt3(x+2)$$
$$y\ge -\sqrt3(x+2)$$